# How to use xsl:variable in xsl:choose

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Hey I have one xsl variable that I want to use in xsl choose tag

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="1 eq whatever">
             <xsl:variable name="name" select="Person/Name"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It will give exception

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:828)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTransformer(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:617)
    at com.navaera.sunflower.set.util.XmlElementsBuilder.getXMLOutput(XmlElementsBuilder.java:189)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not *using* the variable `name` inside `xsl:choose` - you *declare* it there.

To declare a variable inside an `xsl:when` only makes sense if you also make use of this variable inside the same element. This is because of the *scope* of a variable. If you declare a local variable inside `xsl:when`, you cannot use it outside.

Using `xsl:choose` only makes sense if you test at least two different conditions, one inside `xsl:when`, the other in `xsl:otherwise`. If there is only one condition, `xsl:if` will suffice.

If you reveal more of your XSLT stylesheet it might be possible to tell where you went wrong. So, please update your question with a complete input XML and a complete XSLT stylesheet.

**EDIT**: To make this even clearer: No, it is not possible to use a local variable outside of its scope. If you declare a variable inside `xsl:when` you'll never be able to access it outside.

Comment: Hey I have more xslt stylesheet. I think its scope issue then how can i use that variable in outside can you suggest me.?

Comment: @nrvmodi What (I think) you are trying to achieve is not possible. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a global variable

```
<xsl:variable name="name" select="Person/Name"/>
```

and call it inside a template

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="1 eq whatever">
             <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I agree with you but I have lots of variable and I want to define that in condition base... that's why I am asking , Is there any way to do that.?

Answer (score 0):

If you ask the question "I want to write + 3 5", you will get the answer "you can't do that, the language doesn't allow it". If you change the question to "I want to add three to five", people will tell you to write "3 + 5". So please explain your problem, and then we can tell you the right way to code it. We can't work out what the problem is by looking at incorrect code.